# Copy data from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed unsigned byte array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, callback, jna

I have a c# code I am trying to implement in Java using JNA currently stuck in returning a preview image during my device scan process

**C#**

```
[DllImport("RS_SDK.dll",
          CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
        EntryPoint = "RS_RegisterPreviewCallback")]
        public static extern int RS_RegisterPreviewCallback(int deviceHandle, RSPreviewDataCallback captureCallback); 


public delegate void RSRawPreviewCallback(int errorCode, byte[] imageData, int imageWidth, int imageHeight);


RSPreviewDataCallback previewCallback = new RSPreviewDataCallback(previewDataCallback);

private void previewDataCallback(int deviceHandle, int errorCode, IntPtr imageData, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
        {
            log("previewDataCallback called....");
            if (imageData != null)
            {
                int prevImageWidth = imageWidth;
                int prevImageHeight = imageHeight;
                byte[] prevImageData = new byte[imageWidth * imageHeight];
                Marshal.Copy(imageData, prevImageData, 0, imageWidth * imageHeight);
                
                RSRawPreviewCallback callback = new RSRawPreviewCallback(previewCallbackInt);
                Invoke(callback, errorCode, prevImageData, prevImageWidth, prevImageHeight);
            }
            log("previewDataCallback done....");
        }

m_result = RS_RegisterPreviewCallback(deviceHandle,previewCallback);
```

**My Java implementation so far**

```
public interface RSPreviewDataCallback extends Callback {
        void RSPreviewDataCallback(int deviceHandle, int errorCode, Pointer imageData, int imageWidth, int imageHeight);
    }

public interface RS_SDK extends StdCallLibrary {
        RS_SDK INSTANCE = (RS_SDK)
                Native.load("RS_SDK_64", RS_SDK.class);

int RS_RegisterPreviewCallback(int deviceHandle, RSPreviewDataCallback captureCallback);
}

    @Override
    public void RSPreviewDataCallback(int deviceHandle, int errorCode, Pointer imageData, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {

        byte[] dataByteArray = new byte[imageWidth * imageHeight];
        System.arraycopy( imageData, 0, dataByteArray, 0, imageWidth * imageHeight);
        try {
            String data = new String(dataByteArray, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and I run into this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: arraycopy: source type com.sun.jna.Pointer is not an array
    at java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
```

I believe the `imageData` is a memory reference of the byte array and `Marshal.Copy(imageData, prevImageData, 0, imageWidth * imageHeight);` copies the location in memory to the bitmap array.

1. I am not sure if my interface `RSPreviewDataCallback` signature is correct
2. I don't know if there is a JNA equivalent to copy the memory location to a byte array

Comment: Your callback `RSPreviewDataCallback` defines a `deviceHandle` parameter that your C# version doesn't have. What happens if you remove that?

Comment: code has been edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding question 2, the JNA call to get a byte array from a `Pointer` is [`Pointer.getByteArray()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.6.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#getByteArray-long-int-).  So you could grab the bytes from the pointer using `imageData.getByteArray(0, imagewidth * imageheight)`.

Note that Java does not have unsigned `byte` variables, so while the binary will be correct, you'll have to perform a conversion to a wider type to get the positive value. The bitmask `b & 0xff` will widen to an `int` for you and restore the "unsigned" value.

Regarding question 1, the mapping will work if you use the answer to question2.  In most JNA function mappings of arrays, you can simplify this by putting a `byte[]` array as the argument. However, JNA requires specifically mapped types for callbacks, so primitive arrays aren't included, so the `Pointer` method is preferred.

Comment: I have tried using `byte[]` and `int[]` which throws `IllegalArgumentException: Callback argument class [B requires custom type conversion` 
obviously not the expected argument for the native call
But currently the `Pointer.getByteArray().` is returning some negative values in some byte eg: -1 but value changes as I place object on the hardware device
when I debug on the `c#` code I get 255 for a white image instead of the -1 I currently get in `Java`

Comment: Java does not have unsigned types. -1 is 255, in binary. To get the actual value you'll have to use a bit-widening conversion, e.g., `byte & 0xff` (then leave as `int` or cast to `short`.)